# Strange MYSQL Errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

My Query in file looks like this in the php file:

```
SELECT
            p.products_id as v_products_id,
            p.products_model as v_products_model,
            p.products_image as v_products_image,
            p.products_price as v_products_price,
            p.products_sku as v_products_sku,
            p.products_upc as v_products_upc,
            p.products_weight as v_products_weight,
            p.products_date_added as v_date_added,
            p.products_date_available as v_date_avail,
            p.products_tax_class_id as v_tax_class_id,
            p.products_quantity as v_products_quantity,
            p.manufacturers_id as v_manufacturers_id,
            subc.categories_id as v_categories_id
            FROM
            zen_products as p,
            zen_categories as subc,
            zen_products_to_categories as ptoc
            WHERE
            p.products_id = ptoc.products_id AND
            p.products_model = 'M150XN05' AND
            ptoc.categories_id = subc.categories_id
```

I am getting an error returned:
MySQL error 1054: Unknown column 'p.produc1925ts_tax_class_id' in 'field list'
When executing:

```
SELECT
            p.products_id as v_products_id,
            p.products_model as v_products_model,
            p.products_image as v_products_image,
            p.products_price as v_products_price,
            p.products_sku as v_products_sku,
            p.products_upc as v_products_upc,
            p.products_weight as v_products_weight,
            p.products_date_added as v_date_added,
            p.products_date_available as v_date_avail,
                    -- extra 1925 here
            p.produc1925ts_tax_class_id as v_tax_class_id,
            p.products_quantity as v_products_quantity,
            p.manufacturers_id as v_manufacturers_id,
            subc.categories_id as v_categories_id
            FROM
            zen_products as p,
            zen_categories as subc,
            zen_products_to_categories as ptoc
            WHERE
            p.products_id = ptoc.products_id AND
            p.products_model = 'M150XN05' AND
            ptoc.categories_id = subc.categories_id
```

Whats going on how are the extra "1925" getting placed into the middle of the selection? Im at a loss, I have tried everything I can think of that could possibly be causing this.

Code in entirety is here http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=Q2RHT00W

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: sure its all here http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=Q2RHT00W

Comment: And your `ep_query` function?

Comment: odd, try reuploading the file. maybe its corrupt.

Comment: This sounds stupid, but try deleting the line and rewriting it (manually). Similar things have happened to me, where there was some random unicode character that my text editor didn't display but was messing up the code. Worth a try.

Comment: I've made the experience, that mysql* extensions in PHP cannot handle comments in statements, do do remove the out commented line

Comment: ep_query function is here [link](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=hNJiGmaw)

Comment: The commented out line is where the issue is occurring, just forgot to uncomment it before posting the snippet here, its is being used uncommented.

Comment: As Christian suggested, try deleting and retyping. There may be an U+1925 character or something like that in the text that your editor isn't displaying.

Comment: @rabudde, comments in queries work fine with the native MySQL extension.

Comment: @Brad correct, when I image right, this occured with PEAR::DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL doesn't parse implicit joins as you would expect.

(Quote removed because it was the wrong paragraph, but this IS a known bug which I have run into before!)

To avoid confusion, I'd recommending using explicit joins instead:

```
zen_products as p,
zen_categories as subc,
zen_products_to_categories as ptoc
WHERE
p.products_id = ptoc.products_id AND
p.products_model = 'M150XN05' AND
ptoc.categories_id = subc.categories_id
```

Becomes

```
zen_products as p
JOIN zen_products_to_categories as ptoc
    ON p.products_id = ptoc.products_id
JOIN zen_categories as subc
    ON ptoc.categories_id = subc.categories_id
WHERE p.products_model = 'M150XN05'
```

Comment: I don't know whether using the explicit join syntax can help to get rid of the problem, but the 'explanation' you have found is absolutely irrelevant, in my opinion. The extract you are quoting is about mixing implicit and explicit joins in one query, which is not the case here.

Comment: Ah, I apologize.  I grabbed the wrong paragraph.  I know for sure that my diagnosis and solution are correct, though, because I ran into the exact same problem two weeks ago!  Will remove the quote now and add back the correct one later.